# databinding with recyclerview I need help.get root not found

Tags: android

```
       public class Orderlist_recyclerview_adapter extends    
        RecyclerView.Adapter<Orderlist_recyclerview_adapter.MyViewHolder> {

        private Context mContext;
         private ArrayList<Orderlist_contents_bindingmodel> mUsersList = null;

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public Orderlist_recyclerview_adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Orderlist_contents_bindingmodel> usersList) {
        mContext = context;
        mUsersList= usersList;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
//       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.each_row,viewGroup,false);
        OrderlistAdapterContentsBinding binding = OrderlistAdapterContentsBinding.inflate(inflater);
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(binding);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {
        Orderlist_contents_bindingmodel user = mUsersList.get(i);
        myViewHolder.vBinding.setOrderlist_model(user);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUsersList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        OrderlistAdapterContentsBinding vBinding;
        public MyViewHolder(OrderlistAdapterContentsBinding binding) {
            **super(binding.getRoot());**here is the error
            this.vBinding = binding;
        }
     }
    }
```

I need to know how to bind recyclerview adapter model with row layout.

I have already declared these things

```
<data>
    <variable name="orderlist_model" type="anpi.com.propuesta.binding_models.Orderlist_contents_bindingmodel" />
</data>
```

and I have textviews but errors like this are still happening:

- `no resource type found with (text=@{..})`
- `binding .getroot not found`

Answer (score 1):

Posting this even though it seems the question was asked a really long time ago. Adding

```
import android.databinding.ViewDataBinding;
```

did the trick for me.